# htaccess CodeIgniter Subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I'm trying to setup subdomains on a website of mine but I seem to be running into a problem. I'm using CodeIgniter to handle the websites, as `/site/user1`

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/site/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

For some strange reason when it redirects it redirects to http://domain.com/site// when ever I use a subdomain for example `user3.domain.com`

I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect user3.domain.com to a folder on the server?

Comment: It's a dynamic folder. I think I need a rewrite so that it goes to the domain on the server, it's currently going to /www which is a folder on my server.

Comment: You want it to redirect to http://domain.com/site/user3 when you type in the subdomain user3.domain.com?

Comment: yes but it has to be dynamic. I've setup wildcards but for some strange reason when I do a request for user3.domain.com it redirects to domain.com/site/www (not sure why it's putting www there?)

Comment: do you want the URL to change or stay keep the subdomain in the address bar?

Comment: Stay the same if possible. I believe that's done by using [P]

Comment: It appears ok, do you have anything else in that htaccess and what does your vhost config look like?

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/domain
 ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Nothing really unusual...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47195/discussion-between-xiy-and-panama-jack)

Comment: are you create subdomain on server or all work will be done with .htaccess routing only? i am working on same problam. please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to do it like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^((www\.)?)domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/site/%1/$1 [L,NC,P]
```

Comment: am i need  create subdomain on server or all work will be done with .htaccess routing only? i am working on same problam. please tell me